# Programmatically searching files and folders inside specified Document Library

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

By request I'm developing a custom WebPart where it's possible for the user to search files and folders inside a document library, i made a GridView to list the files (working ok I'm not searching), a TextBox for input and a button.

My document library structure is something like this:

> - Document Library
>
>   - Child Folder 1
>   - Child Folder 2
>
>     - Grand Child Folder
>     - Image.jpg

When using the search I created, I type the name 'Image'. But it always returns nothing (SPListItemCollection.count is always 0).

For the search, i'm using the following code:

```
SPQuery query = new SPQuery();

query.ViewAttributes = "Scope='RecursiveAll'";

String caml = @"<Where>
                    <Contains>
                      <FieldRef Name='Title' />
                      <Value Type='Text'>{0}</Value>
                    </Contains>
                </Where>
                <OrderBy>
                  <FileRef Name='ID' Ascending='True' />
                </OrderBy>";

query.Query = String.Format(caml, "Image");
SPListItemCollection resultGetItems = list.GetItems(query);
```

Anyone can help me with this one? i can't seem to get it working.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Have you set the title of the file? Usually it's the name that is set, so you have to use FileLeafRef as the name in the FieldRef

Comment: That did it. Thanks a lot!!! I was almost getting there, I saw it was returning a exception on the title right after i posted, but didn't think of the FileLeafRef attribute. Thanks a bunch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try modifying the title to "FileLeafRef" in the query.

The internal Column name inside the folder is "FileLeafRef".

Please see the below link:

http://sudarsansharepointblog.blogspot.in/2012/10/caml-query-documents-from-sharepoint.html

Please Let me know if it works for you.